# As a non-Arabic speaker who only knows English, I want to begin to learn the Qur'an in it's classical Arabic language. Where do I start?

Tags: quran, arabic

As the title says. I know no Arabic, but want to start with learning. I am mostly looking for recommended literary works or courses. God bless.

Comment: This question's topic is a better fit on language learning SE. On the other hand as is written this is too subjective to be a suitable question on any stackexchange site.

Comment: You mean you want to learn to read Quran?. I don't think anyone can say that there is one single course or literary work that is best but there are many. If you are unable to find someone to teach you Quran in person, then always you can opt for an online alternative. There are numerous courses and classes which teaches you Arabic as well as Quran according to tajweed. May Allah ﷻ guide you.

Comment: bayyinah tv has an arabic course. ITS PERFECT for those wo know English.. note- it only focuses on classical  arabic used by Quran NoT modern arabic .  .. also there is  free  courses on YouTube called ''madina arabic course for English speaking students''    by University of Toronto. one of the greatest  gem out there.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to learn the Holy Quran and the Arabic language? Or just reading the [Noble Qur’an](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_Quran_(Hilali%E2%80%93Khan)) while understanding the meanings of the verses? The easiest way is to learn the Qur’an through online Qur’an lessons. There are many courses online to teach Arabic, read the Holy Qur’an, and memorize the Qur’an also for non-Arabic speakers, like [Bein Quran Academy](https://beinquran.com/) , [Al azhar](http://www.azhar.edu.eg/En/) ..etc.
may God grant you success.